# TeXbook headers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, knuth

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                      % corpo del font principale
               a4paper,%                   % carta A4
               twoside,%         % fronte-retro
               %openright, % capitoli sempre pag destra
               openany % elimina pagine bianche 
               %dvipsnames
               ]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\frontmatter{% 
    \cleardoublepage 
  \@mainmatterfalse 
  \pagenumbering{Roman}} 
\makeatother
\addtolength{\headwidth}{1.5em}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage}\quad\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{\rightmark}\quad\textbf{\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Kafka}
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\section{Storia}
Gregorio Samsa, svegliandosi una mattina da sogni agitati, si trovò trasformato, nel suo letto, in un enorme insetto immondo. Riposava sulla schiena, dura come una corazza, e sollevando un poco il capo vedeva il suo ventre arcuato, bruno e diviso in tanti segmenti ricurvi, in cima a cui la coperta da letto, vicina a scivolar giù tutta, si manteneva a fatica. Le gambe, numerose e sottili da far pietà, rispetto alla sua corporatura normale, tremolavano senza tregua in un confuso luccichio dinanzi ai suoi occhi. Cosa m’è avvenuto? pensò. Non era un sogno. La sua camera, una stanzetta di giuste proporzioni, soltanto un po’ piccola, se ne stava tranquilla fra le quattro ben note pareti. Sulla tavola, un campionario disfatto di tessuti - Samsa era commesso viaggiatore e sopra, appeso alla parete, un ritratto, ritagliato da lui - non era molto - da una rivista illustrata e messo dentro una bella cornice dorata: raffigurava una donna seduta, ma ben dritta sul busto, con un berretto e un boa di pelliccia; essa levava incontro a chi guardava un pesante manicotto, in cui scompariva tutto l’avambraccio. Lo sguardo di Gregorio si rivolse allora verso la finestra, e il cielo fosco (si sentivano placeat facere
\section{Pangramma}
Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo zelante assaggia il whisky ed esclama: alleluja! Aquel vituperable xenófobo apasionado prueba su güisqui y exclama: ¡Aleluya! Ma la volpe col suo balzo ha raggiunto il quieto Fido. Quel vituperabile xenofobo.
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the headers like in the TeXbook. How can i do this?

Comment: Right? Not compilable, so it's hard to say. ;-)

Comment: You're right I have edited my question...

Comment: +1 for providing a MWE, but you should (re-)add some accompanying text.

Comment: re edited ! ; )

Comment: I meant the question text outside your example. :-)

Comment: sorry I haven't even noticed that i have eliminated it.. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding an estimated value of 1.5em to the `\headwidth` length (which results in incorrect spacing for anything but one-digit page numbers), I suggest to typeset the page numbers in appropriately aligned boxes of width 0pt.

Minor enhancements: The TeXbook does use "Chapter/Appendix" prefixes, and it typesets the headers in an italic (not slanted) font (check the design of, e.g., the letter "a").

Note the use of the [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) dummy text package in my example.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{\thepage}\quad}\textit{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{\rightmark}\makebox[0pt][l]{\quad\textbf{\thepage}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
    \@chapapp\ \thechapter:\ \fi #1}{}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```